# How to solve the issue "cannot access org.openqa.selenium.internal.WrapsElement"?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using:

- Java 11
- Selenium 4.9.0

  ```
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>4.9.0</version>


  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.9.0</version>
  ```

When compiling I get the following error:

```
cannot access org.openqa.selenium.internal.WrapsElement
```

Output from Maven compilation:

```
[ERROR]   class file for org.openqa.selenium.internal.WrapsDriver not found
```

The part of the problematic code is the `getNgElement` method below:

```
if (eventsReportPage.newEventButton.getNgElement().isDisplayed())
```

Some suggested to add the `selenium-api` dependency which I did but unfortunately it didn't help.
When I look for the class `WrapsDriver`, the IDE correctly finds it.

Comment: After few hours of investigation I just found that the NgWebDriver class included in jprotractor 1.0 refers to the org.openqa.selenium.internal.WrapsDriver class whereas in selenium-api this class is located in org.openqa.selenium.WrapsDriver. Not sure if this can be changed as jprotractor is not maintainable

Answer (score 0):

The NgWebDriver class included in jprotractor 1.0 refers to the org.openqa.selenium.internal.WrapsDriver class whereas in selenium-api this class is located in org.openqa.selenium.WrapsDriver